# Class To Number

Tags: python

I'm a rookie. I have a question about `class`.
Here's my code:

```
class randcolour:
    def randc(self):
        self.r = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.g = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.b = random.randint(0, 255)
        return (self.r, self.g, self.b)

colour = randcolour()
colour2 = randcolour()
colour3 = randcolour()
colour4 = randcolour()
```

But it said"TypeError: invalid color argument"
How can I do?
int(randcolour)?

Comment: Please share your code as plain text.

Comment: Gosh, why an image? You had more work to create and put an image here than just copy+past the simpel snipped you have!

Comment: You need to provide full example code. There is for example no "it" that could have said "TypeError" in any of the code you have shown. Anyhow, most of your questions should be answered by going through a Python tutorial. Check out the Python homepage for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a class with a method and then instantiating the class. For such a simple object, it should be enough to just use a function. I would do this:

```
def randcolour():
    return (random.randint(), random.randint(), random.randint())
```

which is a function that returns a tuple with 3 random values.

Answer (score 1):

your RandColour class(capitalize first character of each word by convention) should be:

```
import random
class RandColour:
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = random.randint(0,255)
        self.g = random.randint(0,255)
        self.b = random.randint(0,255)

    def get_colour(self):
        return (self.r, self.g, self.b)
```

then you can create a RandColour object and get the random colour:

```
c = RandColour()
c.get_colour()
```

initialization of instance variable should be performed in the **init** function.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are trying to implement.

```
import random 

class RandColor(object):

def randc(self):
    self.r = random.randint(0,255)
    self.g = random.randint(0,255)
    self.b = random.randint(0,255)
    return (self.r,self.g,self.b)

color = RandColor()
color.randc()

print color.r
```

Rather than this , I prefer you try using init method

```
import random

class RandColour:
def __init__(self):
    self.r = random.randint(0,255)
    self.g = random.randint(0,255)
    self.b = random.randint(0,255)

def return_colour(self):
    return (self.r, self.g, self.b)

color = RandColour()
```

The object gets initialised directly.

To obtain the values

```
color.return_colour()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `__init__` for your class. This means when you say

```
coulor = randcolour()
```

your `randc` function never gets called. If you replace

```
def randc(self):
```

with

```
def __init__(self):
```

you will probably get the desired behavior (although your question isn't totally clear, so this may not be what you want).

Another way to make sure your fields are getting set would be to change your calls to be like this:

```
colour = randcolour().randc()
```

The big take-away is that `self.r`, `self.g`, and `self.b` are never being set in the driver code you've provided.